# How to allow users to respond to a question with multiple answers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am making a Google Form and one of the questions I'm asking is about the classes someone has taken during an exchange abroad.

I, therefore, need to simply ask them "What classes did you follow ?" and allow them to add multiple answers but I haven't found a way to enable a question to be given multiple answers.

I have no given list of "classes" that they could have taken which is why I need to accept all the answers they give as in someone could answer "Maths, Physics, Business" and another could answer "Business, Computing, Sports, Chemistry" and I'd need all these answers.

I've been told that using a web app is better than Google Forms but I don't have time to learn how to do that (nor does it benefit my project).

Comment: Use checkboxes or checkboxes grid

Comment: This only allows for one submitted answer..

Comment: No. It allows multiple answers.

Comment: Have you seen the answer to your question? Have you tried it? Did it work for you?. If so, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)) If not let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use checkboxes.

**You should though add the `"OTHER"` option as well**.

Please have a look at the image below on how to create the checkboxes:

[image: flow screenshot]

You can also check what the final form would look like by visiting this sample form: [multiple answers](https://forms.gle/D9EnEFUwqooLGkNb9).